# Python, SQLite: Apostrophe in '%s'

Tags: python, sqlite, apostrophe

I'm getting a syntax error when trying to execute SQLite3 query. The problem is because variable inputPattern contains 's.

The function is:

```
def searchForExactEnglishToCzechTranslation(inputPattern,db):
    if "\'" in inputPattern:
        inputPattern.replace("'","''")
    result = db.execute("SELECT czech FROM translations WHERE english='%s'"  % (inputPattern)).fetchall()
```

I'm trying to replace the sign ' but still isn't working.

Will you give me an advice? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use interpolation; use SQL parameters:

```
def searchForExactEnglishToCzechTranslation(inputPattern,db):
    result = db.execute("SELECT czech FROM translations WHERE english=?",
                        (inputPattern,)).fetchall()
```

This takes care of quoting (the `?` is not surrounded by quotes) and escaping.

Quoting the [`sqlite3` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html):

> Usually your SQL operations will need to use values from Python variables. You shouldn’t assemble your query using Python’s string operations because doing so is insecure; it makes your program vulnerable to an SQL injection attack (see http://xkcd.com/327/ for humorous example of what can go wrong).
>
> Instead, use the DB-API’s parameter substitution. Put `?` as a placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple of values as the second argument to the cursor’s `execute()` method. (Other database modules may use a different placeholder, such as `%s` or `:1`.)

Comment: @roippi: the respect is mutual; see http://xkcd.com/353/ and / or open up Python and type in `import antigravity`.